# Online status for Jabber bot

Tags: python, xmpp

I use xmpppy library for creating my bot. I run the bot and it works correctly, but when I enter to MirandaIM with other user account(not bot account) for testing it I see that its status is offline. Although I can send and receive messages. How can I send to all bot's 'friends' that it is online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage presence with your bot you need to:

- Make sure the roster is properly defined. For example, you bot contact and your user should be each other in their respective contact list.
- Once it is done, send a presence packet when you login and you should see the presence properly broadcasted.

Reference document is: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#int